# Why am I unable to hide the my single-choice AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to display a dialog that allows the user to choose a value using this snippet of code:

```
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.objActivity);
           builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog with ListView");
           builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
           builder.setSingleChoiceItems(lstNames.toArray(new CharSequence[lstNames.size()]), 1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int intItem) {

                   PreferenceCategory targetCategory = (PreferenceCategory) StopFinder.this.objActivity.findPreference("monitored_stops");
                   final Preference account = new Preference(StopFinder.this.objActivity);
                   account.setKey(lstIds.get(intItem));
                   account.setTitle(lstStops.get(intItem));
                   account.setSummary(lstNumbers.get(intItem));
                   targetCategory.addPreference(account);
                   dialog.dismiss();

               }
           });
           final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
           alert.show();
```

When the user chooses an item, I'd like to dismiss the dialog but I haven't been able to do so?

I've read that i need to dismiss the `alert` but the `alert` is initialized after my `onClick` method so I don't know how I would dismiss this. I'm sorry that I've asked this same question like the others for the millionth time but I haven't been able to wrap my head around this scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setItems()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems%28java.lang.CharSequence%5B%5D,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29), instead of `setSingleChoiceItems()`.

It will dismiss the dialog on an item click, and call your callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can declare the alert as private variable of class and then you can assign it the value before calling on click and dismiss using `alert.dismiss()` in onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your alert before your onCreate(); like this

```
AlertDialog alert;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Then use `alert.dismiss();` instead of `dialog.dismiss();`

Also, replace `final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();`

by `alert = builder.create();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
builder.create().show();
```

instead of

```
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```